# PostgreSQL check if values in a given list exist in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

Given below table in Postgres:

| id | some_col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | a |

I want to get output as id and true (if at least one row with that id is present in the table) or false (if no rows with that id are found in the table).

For example where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | true |
| 3 | true |
| 4 | false |
| 5 | false |

I tried with the group by and case with conditions, but is there any optimized/performance SQL way of achieving this? Bcz, `groupby` does complete rows count which is unnecessary in this scenario. And, with `exists` query I didn't find a way to deal with multiple rows return;

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You need to OUTER JOIN the values 1 - 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` clause won't do it. You need to build a list of values somehow (the `values` table valued constructor works in most rdbms) and outer join with it:

```
SELECT x.id, EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM t
    WHERE t.id = x.id
) AS value
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) AS x(id)
```

Comment: could you pls explain if this would count all rows for each id internally? Bcz for each id, I may how thousands of rows in my case. I want to eliminate that.

Comment: You don't need the `CASE` expression. `EXISTS()` already yields a boolean.

Comment: would `limit 1` to subquery help for your answer?

Comment: Added limit 1 to the subquery of your answer. It worked. Thankyou.

Comment: @Forece85 no limit is not required. It is wrapped inside `exists` so basically it means check for presence of rows - 1 row or 1000 rows does not matter.

Comment: @SalmanA The DBMS name is even mentioned (spelled wrong) in the title.